# Why Does my Mac Book Pro not complete two factor authentication steps

Tags: macos, operating-system, two-factor-authentication

I keep getting a notification on my Mac Book Pro in settings->iCloud about how I need to complete two factor authentication but very time I click on 'Continue' a dialogue pops up saying 'Enter your password and a verification code to finish setting up two-factor authentication on this Mac.' So I click on 'Continue' to do just that but nothing else happens. Can anyone explain what is going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to complete two factor authentication by giving the system enough time to respond and approving from another trusted device.